# Cleaning up .NET data structures for GC

Tags: .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, dispose

Does it make difference to clean up the data structures, when they are not needed anymore? I don't mean disposing the disposables - it's obviously required, but, for example, cleaning up dictionaries, lists or other structures to reduce the number of references to objects.

Does it help GC to free the memory faster when there are less refferences (simpler GC graph)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't. If a "parent" object isn't reachable, then its "child" references won't be traversed anyway, so they make no difference.

More importantly, clean-up code generally acts as a distraction from the *real* code. It's *very rarely* worth explicitly setting variables to null etc in an effort to help the garbage collector. There *are* times when it's worth doing, but they usually suggest that perhaps you should refactor your code anyway (e.g. to use smaller methods if you were setting local variables to null, or creating smaller objects if you were setting instance variables to null).

Comment: Still, the GC has to fully know who references who in order to perform relocation (even though that shouldn't happen more than a handful of times in an object's lifetime). Do you have an idea of the overhead involved?

Comment: @zneak: I don't, but surely that's irrelevant if the object is going to be eligible for garbage collection anyway.

Comment: Ok, I understand the GC memory management philosophy. I'm speaking of performance critical layer, which can allow rough, but effective code - it's well hidden on the low layer and has a good facade for the upper layers.

So the question is - how critical can this overhead be for the performance critical code.

Comment: @dip_the_coder: Even so, it shouldn't affect performance at all except in some pathological edge cases where it would suggest design changes anyway. As ever, benchmark before making changes which reduce readability. Do you have evidence that GC is actually an issue?

Comment: No, no evidence for now. That's why I'm asking this question - to get an answer from an experienced developer.

Comment: @dip: Okay, in that case follow normal performance practice: decide what your performance requirements are, and regularly test your code in as realistic a fashion as you can. Note any unexpected changes in performance and consider investigating them, and if the performance drops below acceptable levels, use appropriate tools (profiling etc) to determine the causes before trying to address them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two notable situations in which setting things to null will hasten garbage collection:

1. A variable holds a reference which will in fact never be used again, but the code is such that the compiler can't tell that.  Note that while debugging, variables are kept around as long as they're in scope regardless of whether they'll be used again (among other things, since the operator can force them to be used again by setting the execution point to an earlier position in the current scope), but in release builds the compiler may abandon variables that won't be used again (note that this may, if one isn't careful, cause Finalize-related bugs!)

   If a generation-2 object holds a reference to a generation-0 object, the generation-0 object won't be eligible for collection until there is a full generation-2 collection.  That might not happen for quite awhile.  Clearing the reference would allow the generation-0 object to be collected much sooner.

   If an object which needs to be kept alive has one or more fields that hold references which are no longer going to be used, clearing out those references will help the garbage collector.

Unless you have reason to believe that one of those situations is likely to exist, clearing out references is unlikely to be helpful.  The first situation may seem to occur often in debugging, but unless one has reason to believe the compiler won't recognize a variable as obsolete one shouldn't worry about it.  The second may occur during debugging or production, but the specific circumstances required for it to occur aren't terribly common.  The third is the one most worth worrying about.  A common variation occurs when a class holds an array of object references along with a "size" field which indicates how many array elements are "meaningful".  There are four ways to "clear" such a structure:

1. Simply set the size field to zero

   Set the size field to zero, and re-allocate a new (possibly smaller) array, abandoning the old one.

   Set the size field to zero and clear out all the elements of the array.

   Set the size field to zero, clear out all the elements of the array, and then abandon the array and allocate a new one

Setting the size field to zero is the fastest way to "logically" clear out the data structure.  Unless or until it is re-filled with as many items as it had held, however, it will retain references to abandoned elements.  Allocating a new array and abandoning the old one will avoid that problem, but if the array has been around awhile it may result in situation #2 mentioned above.  Clearing out all the elements of the array but keeping the array itself may be the best approach if the array is not particularly large.  Clearing out all the elements and abandoning the array may be the best approach if the array is large and the data structure is not likely to be immediately re-filled with anything close to the number of elements it used to have.

Comment: Are you sure it's in debug builds rather than simply *when you're debugging*? I can't remember for sure, but I thought it was the latter.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I think you're right.  I'll edit my post appropriately.  Thanks.  Do you agree with my other points?  Ironically, I almost forgot #3 even though it's by far the most important.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with your other points. Point #2 is an area I don't know much about, and it *may* be improved in later versions.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I can understand why the generational GC works as it does, though it can sometimes be annoying when objects which are known to be short-lived, especially large ones, get promoted to Gen2.  Do you like my edits?

Comment: In the first point, you're still talking about the compiler whereas I believe it's the JIT which is important. I'll check the rest of the edit later.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Rather than delete the post, as promised I have checked the text and as I suspected before even leaving work that I was wrong.  I appreciate Mr Skeet not outright calling me a bloody idiot on the forum, although he probably wanted to.  I am not sure where I got this idea stuck in my head even after reading the text I referenced, which has a fantastic description of how the garbage collection scheme works.  Anyway, I apologize and admit my error.  Crow tastes bad but I have learned from my errant ways :)

<strike>The CLR keeps an indexor for each object created and increments/decrements as execution moves along.  When an object reference count gets to zero, that memory allocation is scheduled for garbage collection.  References can be decremented by a object going out of scope, the object being set to null, or the IDisposable interface members being called.  The purpose behind implementing IDisposable for your classes would be to clean up resources that are not POCO, or use system resources that are not cleaned up automatically such as file handles, database connections, network streams, etc.  Otherwise, when the object goes out of scope, the memory will be cleaned during the next GC cycle.</strike>

Comment: Are you sure your explanation is accurate? To me, it looks like you're describing a reference counting mechanism rather than a garbage collector; and I'm almost certain that calling `Dispose` doesn't hasten the collection of an object.

Comment: The CLR does *not* use reference counting. Objects don't go out of scope - variables do, and that doesn't change a reference count. IDisposable does *not* impact garbage collection.

Comment: Dispose does not "hasten" garbage collection.  It is a way to clean up objects manually that would be orphaned for lack of a better term when the managed parent is garbage collected.  As for reference counting, that is exactly how the CLR works.  It counts references to objects and when the reference count reaches zero, the object is scheduled for collection.  There is a great section in the book http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-C-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735627045/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1308584831&sr=8-1

Comment: @Bueller: No, it *doesn't* use reference counting - otherwise circular references would cause memory leaks. It finds "live" objects in a mark-and-sweep fashion, except using generations for extra performance. CLR via C# is indeed an excellent book, and I highly doubt that you'll find a description of the CLR using reference counting in there.

Comment: Agree that variables is the word I should have used.  If the CLR does not use reference counting, then someone should notify Microsoft Press to pull this book from the shelves.

Comment: @Bueller: Please can you give a reference to exactly where Richter claims it does? I suspect you're misremembering the book. I don't have a copy with me, but I can certainly verify it when I get home...

Comment: @Bueller: If you agree that Dispose doesn't hasten garbage collection, I suggest you remove the bit of your answer claiming that "or the IDisposable interface members being called" will decrement the reference count (which doesn't exist anyway)...

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have my copy of the text with me at work either and will re-read when I get home.  If I am incorrect in what I said based on memory of my reading, I will post apology and remove my answer.

Comment: @Bueller: I've just looked in my copy, and I certainly can't see anything mentioning reference counting. Admittedly I'd hoped for a definitive statement that it *doesn't* use reference counting, but there's no mention of counting as far as I can see - instead, there's a description of mark-and-sweep.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I picked up my copy and as you knew and I suspected I was wrong.  I have edited my answer to reflect the wrongness and appreciate you having patience with me.  I re-read the text and am still befuddled what I confused this scheme with but that is neither here nor there.  This community is truly blessed to have a mentor such as you in our midst.

Comment: @Bueller: No problem at all. Let me know if you want to discuss any bits which confuse you - or ask a question here, of course :)